# Problem with condition: if a predefined text exists in the database field, then the if condition is satisfied

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

My idea is to insert a condition in the if, if in the specified field in the database it says "smartphone". I have a problem inserting this condition in the if. I would like to obtain that if in the device field of the database it says "smartphone", then the if condition is true. I'm not getting errors, but Hello doesn't print

```
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
        cur = conn.cursor()  

        cursor.execute("SELECT device FROM info")
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result == "smartphone":
            print("Hello")
```

The database is:

```
CREATE TABLE "info" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "address"   INTEGER,
    "number_phone"  INTEGER,
    "device"    INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

The row, for example, is: id,Street Chelsea 23, 0123456, smartphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that your device field on the table is type INTEGER not VARCHAR so the record would never be type string

#### Edit 1

after update the datatype to TEXT try fetching the first value from you record, example:

```
if result[0] == "smartphone":
  print("Hello")
```

if that doesn't work try printing your result on screen to understand the value of your query

Comment: I use Sqlite. VARCHAR is not there. I should set TEXT. Now i've set TEXT, but it still doesn't print Hello. I believe there is some problem with the code I wrote

Comment: Hello now prints correctly, thank you